# Calcular o desvio padrão de um vetor

Tags: c, matemática, equações

Não estou conseguindo resolver a seguinte equação:

[image: Equação]

Aqui está o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    float m, media, sigma, p;
    int vetor[10];
    media = 0;
    m = 0;
    sigma = 0;
    p = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("Digite um número: ");
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        m = m + vetor[i];
    }
    media = m / 10.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        p = p + (vetor[i] - media);
    }
    sigma = sqrt((p * 1)/10);
    printf("Resultado d = %.2f\n", sigma);
}
```

Comment: A sua fórmula, sem colocar o quadrado nas variações individuais de cada elemento, deve retornar zero. Fácil ver: `n` vezes a média de `n` elementos é a mesma coisa da soma dos `n` elementos. Como você está pondo a média como fator positivo e o elemento como fator negativo, a soma de `n` médias vai dar a soma dos `n` elementos, que se anulam

Answer (score 4):

A formula do desvio padrão tem que ter a distância ao quadrado, que não está na sua. Veja esta formula [retirada diretamente da wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em que `(xi- x)²` está levantado a `²`

Nesta formula o `i` começa em `1` e vai até `N` o que corresponde à sua que começa em `0` e vai até `N-1`, não afetando assim os cálculos.

Aplicando essa correção ao seu código:

```
int main(){
    ...
    media = m / 10.0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        p = p + pow(vetor[i] - media,2); //agora quadrado aqui utilizando a função pow
    }
    sigma = sqrt(p/(10-1)); //dividir por 10-1 que faltava, ou 9 se quiser simplificar
    printf("Resultado d = %.2f\n", sigma);

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/UR7c3q)

Comment: O denominador do desvio padrão na fórmula está `n`, mas no código `n-1`. Já vi uso das duas formas para desvio padrão e me parece que ambas estão certas, mas há uma predileção por `n-1` que eu não sei explicar

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Em relação aos indices do somatório não faz diferença e acaba por ser mais pratico para programação começar em 0. Em relação ao denominador são duas versões diferentes. Que é a [versão não corrigida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Uncorrected_sample_standard_deviation) e a [versão corrigida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation), logo ambas são validas apenas representam variantes diferentes de desvio padrão.

Answer (score 4):

A fórmula está errada. Você deve pegar a somatória da variação da média **ao quadrado**.

Eis o seu programa revisado e simplificado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define QTD_ELEMENTOS 5

int main() {
    int vetor[QTD_ELEMENTOS];

    for (int i = 0; i < QTD_ELEMENTOS; i++) {
        //printf("Digite um número: ");
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);
    }

    int somatorio = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < QTD_ELEMENTOS; i++) {
        somatorio += vetor[i];
    }

    float media = somatorio / (float) QTD_ELEMENTOS;

    float variacoes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < QTD_ELEMENTOS; i++) {
        float v = vetor[i] - media;
        variacoes += v * v;
    }

    float sigma = sqrt(variacoes / QTD_ELEMENTOS);
    printf("Resultado d = %.2f\n", sigma);
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/qFAEBf)

Comment: Sobre a fórmula de desvio padrão, já vi usarem como denominador tanto `n` (o seu caso e o do @Lacobus) como `n-1` (fórmula do AP e código do @Isac). Eu tenho a impressão que ambas as formas são válidas, mas vale salientar isso. Em muitas referências eu encontro mais com `n-1` do que com `n`

Answer (score 2):

Considere o seguinte conjunto contendo `10 amostras`:

```
{ 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
```

Em primeiro lugar, calculamos a [média aritmética simples](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9dia_aritm%C3%A9tica) das amostras do conjunto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida, calculamos o desvio de todas essas amostras em relação à média:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, elevamos ao quadrado o desvio de cada amostra em relação à média:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso, somos capazes de calcular a [Variância](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vari%C3%A2ncia):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Calcula-se o [desvio padrão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desvio_padr%C3%A3o) extraindo a raiz quadrada da variância:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um código capaz de calcular separadamente a "Média", a "Variância" e o "Desvio Padrão" de um conjunto de valores:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAXSIZE 10

double media( double s[], int n )
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        sum += s[i];

    return sum / n;
}

double variancia( double s[], int n )
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double dev = 0.0;
    double med = media( s, n );
    int i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        dev = s[i] - med;
        sum += (dev * dev);
    }

    return sum / n;
}

double desvio_padrao( double s[], int n  )
{
    double v = variancia( s, n );
    return sqrt( v );
}

int main( void )
{
    double vetor[ MAXSIZE ];
    int  i;

    for( i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++ )
    {
        printf("Digite um numero: ");
        scanf( "%lf", &vetor[i] );
    }

    printf("Media = %g\n", media( vetor, MAXSIZE ) );
    printf("Variancia = %g\n", variancia( vetor, MAXSIZE ) );
    printf("Desvio Padrao = %g\n", desvio_padrao( vetor, MAXSIZE ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ gcc -lm desvio.c -o desvio
```

Teste:

```
Digite um numero: 2
Digite um numero: 3
Digite um numero: 3
Digite um numero: 4
Digite um numero: 5
Digite um numero: 6
Digite um numero: 7
Digite um numero: 8
Digite um numero: 9
Digite um numero: 10
Media = 5.7
Variancia = 6.81
Desvio Padrao = 2.6096
```

Comment: Alguns (nem todos) botam o denominador do desvio padrão (e creio que dá variância também) `n-1` no lugar de apenas `n`, mas o motivo me é obscuro

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado: Esse denominador `n - 1` que você mencionou é utilizado para "compensar" o desvio padrão quando o valor da média utilizada não é a média real, suas amostras podem ter sido obtidas a partir de outro experimento em um cenário idêntico. Esse [artigo](http://duramecho.com/Misc/WhyMinusOneInSd.html) explica bem o motivo.

Comment: Citando o artigo que mencionou "(...) but if you are calculating the mean value of the data from the data itself (by summing the data & dividing by n or using the button on the calculator) use the n-1 version (...)", não faria mais sentido neste caso usar o `N-1` ?

Comment: @Isac: Eu entendo que se tratam de [duas equações diferentes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desvio_padr%C3%A3o#Exemplos): `1) desvio padrão populacional` e `2) desvio padrão amostral`. No caso da resposta, foi aplicado a equação de *desvio padrão populacional* pois meu conjunto de amostras corresponde à **toda uma população e não parte de uma**. O *desvio padrão amostral*, onde `n - 1`, é usado para calcular quando **apenas uma parte dos dados da população está disponível**.

Comment: Esse [link](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/measures-of-spread-standard-deviation.php) explica melhor ainda a "regra".

Comment: @Lacobus Esse segundo link elabora melhor a aplicação prática dos dois. Ainda assim fica vago a aplicação pratica dos dois nesta questão não? Na minha ótica ambas seriam válidas, uma vez que os 10 valores de `v` na pergunta tanto podem referir 10 notas de 10 alunos como 10 analises de colestrol de 10 indivíduos de uma população larga. Ou estarei a inferir demasiado ?

Comment: @Isac: Você está certo em ambos os sentidos, e não vejo nenhuma inferição em demasia da sua parte, afinal *scientia vincere tenebras*! Acredito que "os fins" de um dado experimento estatístico é o que determina o método mais adequado a ser aplicado. No caso em questão, acredito que o que está vago é justamente a aplicabilidade e os fins do experimento. Logo, concordo com você, **ambas as equações seriam válidas na resposta**.